# There is no response when i publish the restsharp cod program on windows

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, publish, restsharp

i have a code for login by using RestSharp and Newtonsoft.Json packages. this code like this :

```
Dim client = New RestClient("https://api.mysite.com/auth/login")
Dim request = New RestRequest(Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("authentication-key", "123")
request.AddHeader("authentication-id", "123")
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "username=123&password=123", ParameterType.RequestBody)
Dim response As RestResponse = client.Execute(request)

 MsgBox(response.Content.ToString)
    If response.StatusCode.ToString = "OK" Then
        'Save token
        Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ToString)
    End If
```

when i run this code in Visual Studio , it is worked. but when i published it for windows , there is no response in MsgBox . when i run published program in my computer ( installed visual studio ) it is work and show response of server but when i run published code in other computer the response is null. please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days finally i can solve this problem . Tere is 2 reasons for this error .

1- Change `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json` in source Code .

2- Use .NetFamework version 4.7.2 in users computer .